# Strange behaviour of Angular2 Http.post() error callback

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am using `Angular2/Http` to do a post request and send some data to a server:

```
let myheaders = new Headers();
myheaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myheaders });
let resourceStr = '{"foo": "bar"}';
let foo = this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/invalid', resourceStr, options)
.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, 
  error => { 
    console.warn(error.statusText);
  });
```

If the server responds with `NOT FOUND (404)` (e.g., my URL is wrong), the error callback of the Observable will be called but the statusText will be set `Ok`. However, if I change the `Content-Type` in the headers from `application/json` to `text/plain`, the error callback will be called and the statusText will be set to `NOT FOUND` as it is supposed to.

Anybody has the same problem?

PS: I am using Angular2 rc2

Comment: If you call error.json() and use that it returns an object with a message key that will return "Not Found". In the case above it could be as simple as error.json().message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in the rc2 version. The rc3 version which was released ~2 days ago fixes this problem.